# How edit a table for get a new one in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, python, shapefile, attribute-table

I have a shapefile and y want to **transform the attribute table** (image 1) **in other table** (image 2) but I only want to get some fields and values.

From the atribute table I want to transform **FID_malla** field as rows and the **GROUP** fields values as a columns in unique values. Then the table values are filled with **Shape_Area** field values.

I use R language to do it but, **there is any tool in ArcGIS to do that? or I have to do it using ArcPY (UpdateCursor)?**

(image 1)

[image]

(image 2)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want to use the [Pivot Table](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/pivot-table.htm) tool.

Your input field will be `FID_malla`. Your pivot field will be `GROUP`, and your value field will be `SHAPE_Area`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The SQL tools in ArcGIS are not exactly first class and can take a while to find - I can't think of one off the top of my head for that. You could try the [dissolve](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/coverage-toolbox/dissolve.htm) tool as another angle or maybe you can use the underlying database if it is on SDE.

Another option is to use a [QGIS Virtual Layer](https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#id23), which is quite an impressive innovation. If you know how to write SQL, you could write something like

`select sum(x), sum(y) from my_table group by "GROUP"`

giving you quite a lot of flexibility. That's why I tend to prefer raw DBMS systems, or GIS software that interfaces with them well, as they provide a significant amount more power than ArcGIS in general, although at the expense of some complexity.